# How to check the progress of the post request?

Tags: python, rest, sockets

I am using python requests package to send a post request to the server. It will invoke a long-time running function in the server side. The server side looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
import time

server = Flask(__name__)


# for example this program takes 100 seconds to finish
def dummy_program(times_to_run=100):
    count = 0
    for i in range(times_to_run):
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)


@server.route("task", methods=["post"])
def app():
    dummy_program()

    return {'body': 'finished'}, 200
```

The client side will send a post request `response = requests.post('{}/task'.format(url), files=files, data=data)` to this server, and client will only recieve a response after 100 second when the process finished.

**My question is how can I report the progress to the client? for example using a progress bar**.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know of 3 options: Ajax polling, Websockets server or 3rd party API.
For the latter I'd use rejax.io free plan.

after registering your app and pasting required code, invoking a messsage to client looks like this:

```
import urllib.request
import json

key = 'KEYzoVONRA4CdMvDzBZXytPyebwMf3sLrLh'
secret = 'SECRETLJAQpPaB6p31q5UOzOBtsmmnbLqFY6z4'
url = "https://rejax.io:3001/api/server"
body = {
    'app_key' : key,
    'app_secret' : secret,
    'channel' : 'my-channel-name',
    'text' : 'hello from server'
}

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
jsondata = json.dumps(body)
jsondataasbytes = jsondata.encode('utf-8')   # needs to be bytes
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsondataasbytes))
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)
print (response.status)
```

receiving the message on client will look like this then

```
Rejax.listen('my-channel-name', function(text) {
            
    // received text from server
    console.log(text)
    $("#my-progress-bar").css("width", text + "%")

})
```

link: https://rejax.io
disclosure: I wrote it