# How to report status updates to user with Flask-Celery app?

Tags: python, ajax, flask, celery

I am trying to do a Flask application able to run tasks using Celery.
So far, I am able to run the tasks, however I am not sure how to go back to the user and report the progress of the tasks and finally give them the results, for each task independently.

In my `search.html` I have a form that has a button that sends the request to execute the task, I would like it to not only execute the task but to update a container with a table  where it reports the progress. I have tried some things with Ajax and Javascript but I am not experienced in this so I have not been able to produce the behavior I want.

Here is the code involved for `search.html`:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.name_search.label(class="form-control-label") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.list_to_search.label() }}
      {{ form.list_to_search(class="form-control-file") }}
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
  </div>
</form>
```

And the code involved for `app.py` :

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
  form = form_search()

  if form.validate_on_submit():
    name_exp = form.name_search.data
    path_input = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/temps', 'Input')
    
    os.mkdir(path_input)
    list_to_search_path = save_list(form.list_to_search.data, path_input)
    task = running_long_task.apply_async(args = [list_to_search_path, name_exp])
    flash(f'Query received for {form.name_search.data}!', 'success')
    
    ## something here to inform the user that the task is running?
  return render_template('search.html', title ='Search',form = form)

@celery.task(bind=True)
def running_long_task(self, list_to_search_path, name_exp):
  # long task code

def save_list(list_to_search, path_input):
  list_to_search_path = os.path.join(path_input, list_to_search.filename)
  list_to_search.save(list_to_search_path)
  return list_to_search_path
```

I would be grateful if you could advise me on the best way to do this, or direct me to a tutorial for this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options that comes to mind. Ajax polling, Websockets protocol or REST API request to a designated server that does the websockets "thing" for you. See [How to check the progress of the post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68815882/how-to-check-the-progress-of-the-post-request/68818289#68818289) where I have included a sample code for the latter.